# Right div fix width, left div extend to max width?

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s in the same line, `div_left`, `div_right`
I'd like `div_right` have the fixed width 200px, and `left_div` extend to the max width and height of the left page, how could I write this with css?

Comment: Maybe add a piece of html that you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

html:

```
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

css:

```
.right { background: red; height:300px; float:right; width:200px; }
.left { background: green; height:300px; padding-right: 200px; }
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/47YMn/1/

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use `display:table` property like this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/NCkL4/8/

Comment: it seems that it doesn't support IE6?