# Div is not moving nearby divs

Tags: css, html, containers, jsfiddle

I have something like this:

```
<div class="top">top</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom</div>
```

[Relevant code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQxkq/66/)

As you can see, between top and bottom divs, there is a div container. I want this div container to move bottom dive as much as is needed (and i don't want it to be a fixed value - that means if, lets say left container will get much higher - the bottom div will be pushed down as well.

How can i do that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean you want equal height for `#left` and `#right` columns?

Comment: Your left and right divs are positioned absolutely which takes them out of the flow of the document so the bottom element has no way of telling where they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple seeming problem that ends up being kind of tricky. The above suggestion about position:relative vs. position:absolute are a good first step. After that you need to make some room for the set width right div:

```
.left {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    border:1px dashed red;
    padding-right: 50px;      <---
}
```

Then float your right div in the space you made:

```
.right {
    float:right;              <---
    width: 50px;              (This needs to match the padding-right value above.)
    text-align: right;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px dashed blue;
}
```

Finally, put the right div before the left div in the html:

```
<div class="top">top</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom</div>
```

(Tested in Chrome and IE.)

See: [Right div fix width, left div extend to max width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552026/right-div-fix-width-left-div-extend-to-max-width)

You can check out a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/x3QfG/1/

Will that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're using absolute positions for the left/right div's, so you will always need to know the height in order to position the bottom div correctly. What you want to do is float these instead, then clear the floats in the bottom div. That way the left/right can be as high as their contents, and the bottom div will always appear below.

```
.bottom {
    clear: both;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

I've [modified your jsFiddle accordingly](http://jsfiddle.net/FQxkq/72/), and made the right div higher to show how the bottom always appears below.

Comment: Yes but before, the right column had fixed width while left one had the rest of the space. Now you made it 50/50 and i _need_ the right one to be fixed width.

Comment: you can always change the width and set it to whatever you want.. and thanks @Rich for the fiddle.

Comment: @pjp: No not really. When i change width of the right column to 250px and then set left width to 100%, it crashes out.

Comment: you cant logically do that right? you are asking one child to take everything of the parent and then giving 250px to another child. It will crash right! What i meant was you can apply any width that logically fits both the divs inside the container. i.e. the total width of those two divs should not exceed the parent's width.

Comment: @pjp: But how do i do that? You are telling me to put something like right width 150px, and left width ~70% ? I don't like it this way, because i will need to guess what percentage i should put. And what if my parents div width will change? What then?

Comment: see you gotta decide upon one thing and one think only. if you use percentage, you will have to calculate it for both the child divs and apply to them, you cant apply percentage to one and pixel values to the other one. thats a bad practice and it will crash. Try following a grid system. if you want the divs to be fluid, use percentage for both. if you want to have fixed right div anyway, and  rest of the space for the left one, then make use of `overflow` peoperty. set it to `hidden`;

Answer (score 0):

Use `floats` rather than positioning them absolutely. That will make your architecture very much fluid and flexible.

After you apply necessary `float` values to your `.left` and `.right`, use a **clearfix** hack to contain your floated elements within the container. Now whenever any of the `.left` or `.right` divs increase in height, the bottom div will be pushed down.

Answer (score 0):

Make Container Relative and left and right absolute,and for positioning set width rather than using float.